# iOS Reproduce a view n times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a static UITableViewController who has 3 what I call Widgets in them. These widgets display data about a game (score, players etc).

In one of my widget I want to display all the players and there icon. I don't know how many players need to be set because this depends on the result the server gives me.

So what I want is to add N times a UIView for all the players the servers returns. I had an idea to do this in a UITableView, but I read somewhere that I cannot add a UITableView inside a TableViewCell.

I would like to be able to make a "Dummy" UIView inside IB and copy and add this for the amount of players or isn't this possible?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to accomplish? will these scroll, will they all be on top of each other, why cant you use a UITableView? I think we need a little more detail.

Comment: What kind of restrictions are stopping you from using tableView, and wouldn't collectionView be a possible replacement?

Comment: Updated question hope it is clear now

Comment: I thought to do this in a UITableView, but do restrictions I cannot. ????

Comment: Retyped the hole thing Hope is clear now

Comment: Then you should use a dynamic Height (depending of the number of items) for this particular cell. Then add all your views as the cell's subviews (no IB sorry :p) and increment the origins X,Y of their frames so that they will correctly spread in it.

Comment: So no IB I have to completely code the UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend you to do it in code, it's easy you can create subclass on UIView and you can add UIScrollView. You can override initWithFrame to accept array with yours views:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame data:(NSArray*)myViews
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        _viewsArray = myViews;

        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [self addSubview:self.scrollView];

        for (int i = 0; i < _viewsArray.count; i++)
        {
            // This view (v) needs to initialised base on your array content
            id obj = _viewsArray[i];
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];

            [self.scrollView addSubview:v];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

The last bit left to do is set up a frame for views and scrollView and contentSize in layoutSubviews:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self.scrollView setFrame:self.bounds];
    // change your views frames if you need

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, _viewsArray.count * VIEWHEIGHT)];
}
```

Comment: Beware, having a `UIScrollView` in a `UITableView` is not recommended.
This can (will) cause scroll issue

Comment: This UIScrollView is in a UIView not UITableView.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `I had an idea to do this in a UITableView, but I read somewhere that I cannot add a UITableView inside a TableViewCell.` in the question means that this will be in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: It sounds to me like a UICollectionView would come in handy here for you, Id recommend looking at a tutorial for using that if you never have.

Comment: If you have a few view you can use this solution above but if you have a lot of view you should have a look on UICollectionView. UICollectionView reuses views, what is good for app performance. My solution will affect heavily memory (the app can eaven crash) if you add plenty of views to the uiscrollview. It's good for some requirements because it's easy to apply and in some cases it's good enough.